# useEffect not working the same as componentDidUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a parent form component that renders 2 children field components.

The children component have 2 props I use for validation. First the `validateOnLoad` that I can use to trigger a validation check on that component. A second prop is the `onValidation` prop that I use to execute a callback once the validation is complete. The callback will be passed back the `fieldID` and `validationResults` of the validation.

In the parent I have a state that tracks the `confirmEntry` state. This tracks when the *Submit* button was clicked. The parent also has a `ref` called the `firstErrorField` (self explanatory).

What I am trying to do is the following:

1. User clicks on *Submit*.
2. This sets the `confirmEntry` state to `true`. Changing this state should cause my parent to re-render.
3. The value of `confirmEntry` which is now `true` is passed into the children's `validateOnLoad` prop. This triggers the validation on the children component.
4. When the validation is complete, I need do the following:

   1. Check the validation results.
   2. If there is a validation failure mark the `firstErrorField` with the `fieldID` I got back from the validation.
   3. Set the `confirmEntry`to `false`because I don't want the *Submit* to proceed.
   4. Move focus to this specific field so user knows which field they need to address.
   5. However, if the validation is successful continue with the submission.

I am having the hardest time with getting this to work with `useEffect`.

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/0q15mz2p1p) that has both the implementations. In the class implementation you will see that the validation is checked and only proceeds when both the form fields are valid. However, in the hooks implementation, the form submit continues even when the fields are not yet validated.

Any help in this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This was my fix to the question above. It essentially came down to understanding the closures on useEffect.

https://codesandbox.io/s/zw1lp4985l